# Scrapy spider starts fast and slows down gradually

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm scraping 28M pages and my scrapy spider starts fast and slows down gradually.
I doubt it the server blocking me since I can run a second spider and it will start fast again.
Not the hardware, is running on a nice vps with 24gb RAM. Allowed domains is just that site.
What could be the cause of the slowdown?

If I stop the job and immediately resume it it starts fast again

```
2022-11-11 12:25:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-11-11 12:25:39 [scrapy.core.scheduler] INFO: Resuming crawl (97145 requests scheduled)
2022-11-11 12:25:39 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:25:39 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2022-11-11 12:26:39 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 1633 pages (at 1633 pages/min), scraped 1629 items (at 1629 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:27:39 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 3242 pages (at 1609 pages/min), scraped 3238 items (at 1609 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:28:39 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 4736 pages (at 1494 pages/min), scraped 4733 items (at 1495 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:29:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 5914 pages (at 1178 pages/min), scraped 5906 items (at 1173 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:30:39 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 7198 pages (at 1284 pages/min), scraped 7190 items (at 1284 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:31:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 8417 pages (at 1219 pages/min), scraped 8408 items (at 1218 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:32:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 9557 pages (at 1140 pages/min), scraped 9553 items (at 1145 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:33:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 10617 pages (at 1060 pages/min), scraped 10612 items (at 1059 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:34:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 11629 pages (at 1012 pages/min), scraped 11623 items (at 1011 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:35:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 12592 pages (at 963 pages/min), scraped 12587 items (at 964 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:36:39 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 13499 pages (at 907 pages/min), scraped 13493 items (at 906 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:37:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 14368 pages (at 869 pages/min), scraped 14364 items (at 871 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:38:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 15161 pages (at 793 pages/min), scraped 15153 items (at 789 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:39:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 15884 pages (at 723 pages/min), scraped 15881 items (at 728 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:40:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 16665 pages (at 781 pages/min), scraped 16657 items (at 776 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:41:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 17417 pages (at 752 pages/min), scraped 17409 items (at 752 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:42:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 18140 pages (at 723 pages/min), scraped 18132 items (at 723 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:43:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 18844 pages (at 704 pages/min), scraped 18836 items (at 704 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:44:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 19528 pages (at 684 pages/min), scraped 19516 items (at 680 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:45:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 20188 pages (at 660 pages/min), scraped 20180 items (at 664 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:46:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 20836 pages (at 648 pages/min), scraped 20828 items (at 648 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:47:39 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 21460 pages (at 624 pages/min), scraped 21452 items (at 624 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:48:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 22014 pages (at 554 pages/min), scraped 22006 items (at 554 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:49:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 22588 pages (at 574 pages/min), scraped 22580 items (at 574 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:50:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 23159 pages (at 571 pages/min), scraped 23151 items (at 571 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:51:39 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 23731 pages (at 572 pages/min), scraped 23723 items (at 572 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:52:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 24299 pages (at 568 pages/min), scraped 24291 items (at 568 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:53:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 24847 pages (at 548 pages/min), scraped 24839 items (at 548 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:54:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 25385 pages (at 538 pages/min), scraped 25377 items (at 538 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:55:39 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 25917 pages (at 532 pages/min), scraped 25909 items (at 532 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:56:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 26441 pages (at 524 pages/min), scraped 26433 items (at 524 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:57:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 26953 pages (at 512 pages/min), scraped 26945 items (at 512 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:58:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 27442 pages (at 489 pages/min), scraped 27440 items (at 495 items/min)
2022-11-11 12:59:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 27882 pages (at 440 pages/min), scraped 27874 items (at 434 items/min)
2022-11-11 13:00:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 28372 pages (at 490 pages/min), scraped 28364 items (at 490 items/min)
2022-11-11 13:01:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 28856 pages (at 484 pages/min), scraped 28848 items (at 484 items/min)
2022-11-11 13:02:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 29332 pages (at 476 pages/min), scraped 29324 items (at 476 items/min)
2022-11-11 13:03:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 29800 pages (at 468 pages/min), scraped 29792 items (at 468 items/min)
2022-11-11 13:04:39 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 30260 pages (at 460 pages/min), scraped 30252 items (at 460 items/min)
2022-11-11 13:05:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 30720 pages (at 460 pages/min), scraped 30712 items (at 460 items/min)
2022-11-11 13:06:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 31166 pages (at 446 pages/min), scraped 31158 items (at 446 items/min)
```

I've tried autothrottle, another VPS and same results.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't actually slowing down, it just appears that way because of the number of concurrent procedures it is managing at a time.

`AutoThrottle` can help mitigate this behavior but it only effects one end of the scrapy workflow. There is also the output/feeds end of the spider that is also asynchronous and can often time accumulate a large number of concurrent jobs and iterating through all of them will take longer and longer to clear.

Also if you have any custom middleware that happens to be computationally expensive, this can cause a significant slow down as well.

You can use the `CONCURRENT_ITEMS` to adjust the number of output procedures that can be handled concurrently, and also there are `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`, `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN`, and `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP` settings that work similarly to AutoThrottle. Adjustments to any of these could improve the rate of output for your spider.

You can also use the scrapy logging and signals API's to help pinpoint where exactly the slowdown is occurring. However I should note that scrapy will always run faster at the beginning of a crawl. Upon starting/restarting a crawl the scheduler is completely empty and so the first items processed will move through the workflow quickly because of that.